# three.js OBJLoader and precompressed gzip obj not loading

Tags: three.js

This may be unsupported by the library. Just wondering if anyone has come across this. I have tried loading an obj and there is no problem. If i pre-compress to gzip format it will not load and its callback is never called. Be nice to gzip obj files since they get good compression.

There's nothing special in the code.

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);
loader.load(meshUrl, function (sceneObject) {
    sceneObject.traverse(function (child) {
        if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
            child.material = material;
        }
    });
}, onProgress, onError);
```

UPDATE

meshUrl if pointing to an external url that is an uncompressed obj file, loads normal. onProgressed called and behaves as you'd expect.
If pointing to a pre-compressed gzip version of the same obj, the onProgress method is called but progress.total is always 0 which caused my code to funk out.

Fixed, now to handle progress better

Comment: What is the question? Is there some code that is causing a problem that you could show us?

Comment: See my edit above. Got it working, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hate to answer my own question but turns out onProgress is still being called with the total value always being 0 if content is gzipped. So solution is to store total elsewhere, in this case the db that loads the referenced url and calc percentage loaded that way.
Plus the progress parameter has a lengthComputable boolean.